# Duplicate value inserted in the mongodb "_id" field

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

In mongodb, We can assign our own value to _id field and the "_id" field value may be of any type, other than arrays, so long as it is a unique -- From the [docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-The%5CidField).

But in my live database, i can see some records were duplicated as follows,

```
db.memberrecords.find().limit(2).forEach(printjson)
{
        "_id" : "999783",
        "Memberid" : "999783",
        "Name" : "ASHEESH SHARMA",
        "Gender" : "M",
}
{
        "_id" : "999783",
        "Memberid" : "999783",
        "Name" : "Sanwal Singh Meena",
        "Gender" : "M",
}
```

In above records, the same _id value inserted twice in the table. When i tested with local database it is not allowing to insert the same _id record and throwing error as follows,

```
E11000 duplicate key error index: mongoms.memberrecords.$_id_  dup key: { : "999783" }
```

Below is the Indexes for my live memberrecords table(for your reference),

```
db.memberrecords.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "mongoms.memberrecords",
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "v" : 0
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("4f0bcdf2b1513267f4ac227c"),
                "ns" : "mongoms.memberrecords",
                "key" : {
                        "Memberid" : 1
                },
                "name" : "Memberid_1",
                "unique" : true,
                "v" : 0
        }
]
```

Note: i have two sharding for this table.

Any suggestion on this please,

Answer (score 1):

Is your shard key the _id field?  You can only have one unique index enforced across a cluster: the shard key (otherwise the server would have to check with every shard on every insert).

So: on a single a shard, _id will be unique. However, if it isn't your shard key, all bets are off across multiple shards.

See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Limits#ShardingLimits-UniqueIndexesDOCS%3AIndexes%23UniqueIndexes.

Comment: i am using php to query mongo. So to avoid duplicate insert, i need to change the code which will do a select query before insert a record and if record is available then, i need to update the record.

Is there any simplification / workaround available to avoid duplicate insert?